# toward iPython: easy_install can't find my Python(s) on Mac OS 10.5.8

Tags: python, macos, setuptools, ipython, easy-install

Installed setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg on my Mac OS 10.5.8 but then

```
sudo easy_install readline ipython
```

yields a possible script problem?

```
Processing readline-6.2.0.tar.gz
Running readline-6.2.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-N_JiZD/readline-  6.2.0/egg-dist-tmp-9IRgCS
No eggs found in /tmp/easy_install-N_JiZD/readline-6.2.0/egg-dist-tmp-9IRgCS (setup script problem?)
```

and easy_install can't find my Python(s)

```
ERROR: 'IPython requires Python Version 2.6 or above.' 
Exiting.
error: Setup script exited with 1
```

however I just installed 2.7 and my active version is 3.0.1

```
$ ls /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
2.7 3.0 Current
```

based on tips I found here, I tried installing setuptools directly into .../2.7/bin/ but all I got was a lecture from easy_install that

```
setuptools 0.6c11 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
```

another tip I saw here was to run

```
$ python2.7 setup.py install               
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

That result is troubling.  How can I help easy_install find my stuff?  Have I done something goofy?

Comment: Note, Python 3.0.1 was a very early release of Python 3.  It is known to have many issues and was retired immediately upon release of Python 3.1.  Python 3.2.1 is current (with 3.2.2 to be released next week).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I won't be using Python 3-point-anything, at least not for a while, but I'm glad I know to look out for it.

Answer (score 3):

Which version of python is `easy_install` for?  Look at the top of the file listed by `which easy_install`.  I'll bet it's Python 2.6.  See if you have an `easy_install-2.7` or somesuch and use that instead if you do.  If not, then make sure you reinstall setuptools with the *right python version*.

Finally, I don't think you [need to specify](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/install/install.html#readline) `easy_install readline` since it will be installed automatically as a dependency of iPython when iPyhon is `easy_install`ed.

Comment: #!/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Comment: Thanks so much!  easy_install-2.7 ran with lots of 'warnings', but it ran!